# Is it possible to insert an image as a background pattern to mindmap nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds, mindmaps

Suppose I've got the following mindmap:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,shadows}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      [mindmap,
      font=\large\bfseries\sffamily,
      grow cyclic,
every node/.style={concept, circular drop shadow, 
    %minimum size=0pt,
    execute at begin node=\hskip0pt},
      %concept color=magenta!70!black,
      root concept/.append style={
        font=\huge\sffamily\bfseries,text width=8cm,concept color=Gold},
      level 1/.append style={sibling angle=360/10,
        font=%\color{Seashell}
        \bfseries\sffamily
        \LARGE,
        level distance=35em,
        inner sep=0pt,
        text width=4cm,
        sibling distance=1cm,
        concept color=Goldenrod},
      level 2/.append style={%sibling angle=37.5,
        sibling distance=21em,
        font=\color{Seashell}\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{36pt}{48pt}\selectfont,level distance=10cm,inner sep=0pt,text width=7cm,color=purple!50},
]

         \node [root concept] {Root Concept}
         child {node {Node}}
         child {node {Node}}
         child {node {Node}}
         child {node {Node}}
child {node {Node}}
child {node {Node}}
child {node {Node}}
child {node {Node}}
child {node {Node}}
child {node {Node}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It's fine, but I was wondering if it is at all possible to implement a "textured" background for those nodes, as it's possible with other tikz nodes as per [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193555/crop-jpeg-into-circular-tikz-node).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is. One way to achieve this is to put the `path picture` into `nodes` and make sure that then the node you put in the `path picture` does not see the options, which can be achieved by setting locally `every node/.style={}`.

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,shadows}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      [mindmap,
      font=\large\bfseries\sffamily,
      grow cyclic,
every node/.style={concept, circular drop shadow, 
    %minimum size=0pt,
    execute at begin node=\hskip0pt},
      %concept color=magenta!70!black,
      root concept/.append style={
        font=\huge\sffamily\bfseries,text width=8cm,concept color=Gold},
      level 1/.append style={sibling angle=360/10,
        font=%\color{Seashell}
        \bfseries\sffamily
        \LARGE,
        level distance=35em,
        inner sep=0pt,
        text width=4cm,
        sibling distance=1cm,
        concept color=Goldenrod,
        nodes={%
            fill=none,draw,
            path picture={\node[every node/.style={}] at (path picture bounding box.center) 
                {\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=4.1cm]{example-image-duck}};},%},
            },      
        },
      level 2/.append style={%sibling angle=37.5,
        sibling distance=21em,
        font=\color{Seashell}\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{36pt}{48pt}\selectfont,level distance=10cm,inner sep=0pt,text width=7cm,color=purple!50},
]

         \node [root concept] {Root Concept}
         child {node {Node}}
         child {node {Node}}
         child {node {Node}}
         child {node {Node}}
child {node {Node}}
child {node {Node}}
child {node {Node}}
child {node {Node}}
child {node {Node}}
child {node {Node}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you replace `example-image-duck` by `GoldLeaf.jpg` from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/510458/194703) you get

[image]

If you want to make the nodes of more levels golden, you may want to define a style for that.

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,shadows}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\tikzset{golden/.style={
          fill=none,draw,
          path picture={\node[every node/.style={}] at (path picture bounding box.center) 
              {\includegraphics[width=#1,height=#1]{GoldLeaf.jpg}};},%},
          },golden/.default=4cm         
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap,
      font=\large\bfseries\sffamily,
      grow cyclic,
    every node/.style={concept, circular drop shadow, 
    %minimum size=0pt,
    execute at begin node=\hskip0pt},
      %concept color=magenta!70!black,
      root concept/.append style={
        font=\huge\sffamily\bfseries,text width=8cm,concept color=Gold,
        golden=8cm},
      level 1/.append style={sibling angle=360/10,
        font=%\color{Seashell}
        \bfseries\sffamily
        \LARGE,
        level distance=35em,
        inner sep=0pt,
        text width=4cm,
        sibling distance=1cm,
        concept color=Goldenrod,nodes={golden=4cm}
        }]

         \node [root concept] {Root Concept}
         child {node {Node}}
         child {node {Node}}
         child {node {Node}}
         child {node {Node}}
child {node {Node}}
child {node {Node}}
child {node {Node}}
child {node {Node}}
child {node {Node}}
child {node {Node}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that if you want to make the connecting bars follow the pattern, too, you will probably be better off with a different approach using `path fading`, something that I will be happy to spell out at another day.

Comment: The golden leaf image is exactly the kind of image I had in mind. So if I want to repeat the process for the root concept, I should just add `nodes={...}` either to `root concept` or to `every node/.style`, right?

Comment: @Joseph In that case I'd use a style that I apply at different levels. I added this to the answer.

Comment: Great! I'll be glad to make another question in the future regarding the connecting bars.