# Using non-solid colours for fonts

Tags: fonts, color, luatex, fontspec

My marketing dept. devised a scheme for visuals that includes occasional occurences of characters (glyphs) rendered in non-solid colours to go beyond simple gradients. My question is: is there any way I could make a font from, say, a given .otf and a picture containing the colour movement?
(The font itself is proprietary I believe, but that's hopefully not essential here.)

Here's an example:

[image: a few glyphs with non-solid colour]

I have not tried anything because I don't really know where to start. I think there'd be a way with pgf/tikz for individual cases.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/192528/134144 might be interesting.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/510458 may also help.

Comment: Thanks heaps to both of you for the pointers. The first was already pretty close but the answer by Schrödinger's cat in the post @thérèse linked was exactly what I wanted.